# Always returns 'None' when trying to get an element from web page

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, nonetype

I'm trying to get the wins from the 'Overall match stats' on this page: https://www.fctables.com/teams/sunderland-194998/?template_id=11. Everything I try it just returns 'None'. This isn't the only page I have tried to use but every one seems to return 'None'. I'm not very advanced in this so any help would be appreciated.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = "https://www.fctables.com/teams/sunderland-194998/"
response = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

wins = soup.find('div', class_='text-success ')
print(wins)
```

I need it to output the '6' which is the number of wins. Preferably as an integer.

Comment: Try removing the space at the end of `class_='text-success '`.  I see that the space is actually there in the raw html, but I'm guessing the soup parser is trying to be "helpful" by removing it...

Comment: With the space removed, I get `<div class="text-success">11</div>` as the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BeautifulSoup famously is the package that lets
you parse other people's HTML garbage as if it were grammatically correct.
The HTML grammar is, alas, a bit complicated.

You got hung up on the trailing SPACE in the class name.
Just strip it.

```
>>> from pprint import pp
>>>
>>> pp(soup.find_all('div', class_='text-success '))
[]
>>> pp(soup.find_all('div', class_='text-success'))
[<div class="text-success">11</div>,
 <div class="text-success">1.83</div>,
 <div class="text-success">4</div>,
 <div class="text-success">4/6</div>,
 <div class="text-success">5/6</div>,
 <div class="text-success">2/6</div>,
 <div class="text-success">2/6</div>,
 <div class="text-success">41</div>,
 <div class="text-success">2.16</div>,
 <div class="text-success">11</div>,
 <div class="text-success">78.9%</div>,
 <div class="text-success">89.5%</div>,
 <div class="text-success">21.05%</div>,
 <div class="text-success">68.42%</div>]
```

---

Steve Harvey wants to know, "Could SPACE ever be
part of a valid class name?"
Survey [says](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#attributes-2)
"nope!", the SPACE character is specifically prohibited.

Answer (score 1):

You can change how you select the tags:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.fctables.com/teams/sunderland-194998/?template_id=11"
response = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

stats = {}
for li in soup.select("h3:-soup-contains('Overall matches stats') + div li"):
    stats[li.p.text] = li.div.text

print(stats["Wins"])
```

Prints:

```
6
```

---

The `stats` is a dictionary that contains:

```py
{
    "Matches": "11",
    "Goals": "20",
    "per game": "1.82",
    "Wins": "6",
    "Draws": "1",
    "Losses": "4",
    "Over 2.5": "72.7%",
    "Over 1.5": "81.8%",
    "CS": "36.36%",
    "BTTS": "45.45%",
}
```